# How can I notify the CRA of intent to contribute to an RRSP?

Tags: taxes, canada, withholding, rrsp, canada-revenue-agency

I currently have an RRSP through work that I contribute to. However, the amount is significantly smaller than my annual limit. I have a self-managed RRSP separately and contribute sizable amounts. Thus far, I have gotten a large refund every year come tax time, since I claim the full RRSP contribution I've made that year.

Is there any way I can notify the CRA of intent to contribute a large amount to my RRSP in the upcoming year in order to reduce the tax withholdings on each paycheck instead of receiving a large refund at tax time?

Comment: The T1213 form may be the key here, although I don't know for sure, and it sounds like you'd have to have an RRSP payment plan set up

Comment: @tar Thanks - I'd heard there was some form, but wasn't sure what it was - looks like that's it. I wonder if having an existing payment plan is a requirement; I'd much rather do lump-sum.